# jQuery - Set timer to run once then execute a function

Tags: jquery, timer

So I have another plugin that takes a second to load because it has to get some info, so I plan on making it so that it runs on about a 3 second timer, during the 3 seconds it will display something like "Loading Statistics" then slides down the statistics judging that they took 3 seconds or less to load, heres my current code, but it keeps repeating http://jsfiddle.net/7tkGY/

Thanks =) - Necro

Comment: Could be because you're using `setInterval`, which repeats in an interval (duh), and not `setTimeout`, which fires once.

Comment: Sorry, didn't learn jQuery yet =/ I should really start...

Comment: @Necrohhh: This is basic JavaScript. I'd lay off on the jQuery until you understand regular JavaScript.

Comment: Note: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) and setTimeout are defined as part of the DOM (DOM Level 0 in HTML5), e.g. they are not part of jQuery

Comment: Well see here's the thing. I can't even tell the difference between jQuery and regular Java lol. Thank you all though.

Comment: @adeneo ECMAScript is independent of the DOM. The functions defined in `window` (e.g. setTimeout or addEventListener) are either defined in the DOM by W3C or by a defacto-standard (or just a one-off implementation). I believe they were "defacto", but have since been incorporated into HTML5.

Comment: @adeneo See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/timers.html#timers (I am not sure how/if they were defined under HTML4.01, though).

Answer (score 8):

```
window.setTimeout(func,3000);
```

setInterval is a repeating function. if you want to end a setinterval you must do this

```
var interval = window.setInterval(func,3000);
 clearInterval(interval);
```

setTimeout(func,time) runs the function only onces

Answer (score 3):

You can use setTimeout:

```
window.setTimeout(yourfunction, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
window.setTimeout(yourfunction, 2000);
```

Answer (score 1):

setInterval executes the function every 2000ms which isn't wht you want.

Be careful the plugin might take 2seconds to load on your pc but on a slower connection it could take longer and lead to your code breaking.

Jquery's $(function(){}) executes **after** all DOM objects are ready, so you don't really need to guess how long the plugin takes to load.

You can try:

```
function yourfunction() {
     alert('test');
}

$(function (){
    window.setTimeout(yourfunction, 2000);//use yourfunction(); instead without timeout

})
```